# How to access each record when query retrieved all records Yii2

Tags: php, api, yii2

I'm using Yii2 Framework to build simple API , my DB contain questions table and this table contain (question_type) column and the value of this column (1 or 2) and i create a function in Question model to get type each question .. and i create api to retrieve all questions from the table but when call the function this error displayed `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`,, how to solve this problem ,

this is my code in controller

```
public function actionGetQuestions(){
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response:: FORMAT_JSON;
    $attributes = \yii::$app->request->post();
    $questions = Questions::find()->all();
    if($questions){
        return array(
            'status' => true,
            'data' => ['id'=> $questions->id , 'question_content' => $questions->question_content , 'Question Type' => $questions->checkQuestionType($questions->id) ,
            'Question Required Or Not' => $questions->checkQuestionRequired($questions->id) ]
        );
    }else{
        return array('status'=>false,'data'=> 'No Student Found');
    }
}
```

Comment: the result of your code is **array** of **array**, you must return if with foreach or use [findOne()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#findOne()-detail).

Comment: Well it's logical, `$questions` is not an object, it is an array of ActiveRecord instances I believe

Comment: in laravel framework i used make:Resource and i use toArray function to work my problem ,, but in Yii2 i cant solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `all()` returns array of ActiveRecord objects. You must work with the result set with help loop statements and other methods of working with arrays. For example:

```
foreach ($questions as $question) {
   $id = $question->id;
}
```

Of course, if you want to get one object instead of an array of objects you can use [one()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#one()-detail) function. For example:

```
$question = Questions::find()->where(['id' => <id-value>])->one();
$id = $question->id;
```

You should build data to response and return it. For example:

```
public function actionGetQuestions()
{

    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response:: FORMAT_JSON;

    $attributes = \yii::$app->request->post();
    $questions = Questions::find()->all();

    if(!empty($questions)) {
        $data = [];
        foreach ($questions as $q) {
            $data[] = [
                'id'=> $q->id , 
                'question_content' => $q->question_content , 
                'Question Type' => $q->checkQuestionType($questions->id) , 
                'Question Required Or Not' => $q->checkQuestionRequired($questions->id)
           ];
       }

       return [
          'status' => true,
          'data' => $data
       ];
    } else {
       return ['status' => false,'data' => 'No Student Found'];
    }
}
```

Comment: okay ,, but how to return all results to my frontend or postman

Comment: @AhmadAboZaid I updated my answer. Please, look at it.

Comment: yes it worked .. but please edit your answer from  questions to question when call a functions .. thank you :)